# How to merge contacts from two skype account automatically?

Tags: skype, contacts, merge

I have two Skype account and want to merge the two contact list into one quickly. How can I do that?

*Update*

I found myself [one way](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10220/how-can-i-send-a-contact-s-details-to-another-contact-in-skype-for-windows-desktop) to do this, but to accept the sent contacts from the 2nd account, I have to click `add contact` manually which is very tiring! Need to look for a more automatically way i.e. is there an `accept all` button when recieved?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself one way to do this using [import and export contact list](http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Merge-two-accounts/m-p/1593648#M16950)

Comment: But this still require us to re-add old friends

Answer (score 1):

However, what we cannot do is to combine both accounts into one and I can only suggest that you then re-add the Skype contacts that you wish transfer on your default account and sending them a contact request from there.
To view your accounts associated to your email and to reset your password, please refer to this link: https://a.login.skype.com/diagnostics
Click on the link
Enter your email or your Skype name
Select continue to view your accounts
Once there, you can then select which accounts you wish to access or select the account where you want to have your password reset.